# EJB remote lookup namenotfoundexception

Tags: ejb, wildfly, jndi, lookup

I try to remotely access an EJB in an (eclipse) EJB-Project, packaged as a jar, deployed on a WildFly 10.1.0 Final. The server side is no maven-project, so i added ejb-3.0.jar, javaee-api-7.0.jar, jboss-ejb3-ext-api-1.1.0.jar to the java build path.

My server code is:

> ```
> package org.maometto.api;
>
>
> public interface IMyBeanRemote {
>   void sayHello();
> }
> ```

```
package org.maometto.businesslogic;

import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import org.maometto.api.IMyBeanLocal;
import org.maometto.api.IMyBeanRemote;

@Stateless
@Remote(IMyBeanRemote.class)
public class MyBeanImpl implements IMyBeanRemote {

    @Override
    public void sayHello() {
        System.out.println("I am Server");
    }

}
```

When I start the server from within eclipse the log shows:

> 21:06:19,015 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread
>   1-4) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'MyBeanImpl' in
>   deployment unit 'deployment "MyFirstEJB.jar"' are as follows:
>        java:global/MyFirstEJB/MyBeanImpl!org.maometto.api.IMyBeanRemote     java:app/MyFirstEJB/MyBeanImpl!org.maometto.api.IMyBeanRemote
>     java:module/MyBeanImpl!org.maometto.api.IMyBeanRemote
>   java:jboss/exported/MyFirstEJB/MyBeanImpl!org.maometto.api.IMyBeanRemote
>     java:global/MyFirstEJB/MyBeanImpl    java:app/MyFirstEJB/MyBeanImpl
>   java:module/MyBeanImpl

My Client - a converted maven project in an own project- code is as follows:

```
package com.maometto.client;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import org.maometto.api.IMyBeanRemote;

public class EJbClient {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
        //jndiProps.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
        jndiProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        jndiProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:8080");
        jndiProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        try {
            InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(jndiProps);
            IMyBeanRemote iMyBeanRemote = (IMyBeanRemote) initialContext.lookup("java:global/MyFirstEJB/MyBeanImpl!org.maometto.api.IMyBeanRemote");
            iMyBeanRemote.sayHello();

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

To get the remote interface in the client, i added the ejb-project to the java build path of the client project.

The POM of the client is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MyEJBClient</groupId>
  <artifactId>MyEJBClient</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-jms-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-naming</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.marshalling</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-marshalling-river</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jbossall-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-ejb-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.8.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
        <artifactId>wildfly-ejb-client-bom</artifactId>
        <version>11.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I execute the client, i get following stacktrace in the log:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: global/MyFirstEJB/MyBeanImpl!org.maometto.api.IMyBeanRemote -- service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.exported.global.MyFirstEJB."MyBeanImpl!org.maometto.api.IMyBeanRemote"
    at org.jboss.as.naming.ServiceBasedNamingStore.lookup(ServiceBasedNamingStore.java:106)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:207)
    at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:184)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.Protocol$1.handleServerMessage(Protocol.java:127)
    at org.jboss.naming.remote.protocol.v1.RemoteNamingServerV1$MessageReciever$1.run(RemoteNamingServerV1.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I tried it with the other jndiBindings as well.

I also tried it with the "ejb:" namespace and its convention ("ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName). Still same error. I don't know what I'm missing or what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone help me, please?